# Collections emptyList/singleton/singletonList/List/Set toArray

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Suppose I have this code:

```
String[] left = { "1", "2" };
String[] leftNew = Collections.emptyList().toArray(left);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(leftNew));
```

This will print `[null, 2]`. This *sort of* makes sense, since we have an empty list it is somehow suppose to cope with the fact that we are passing an array that is bigger and sets the first element to null. This is probably saying that the first element does not exist in the empty list, thus it set to `null`.

But this is still confusing, since we pass an array with a certain type only to help infer the type of the *returned* array; but anyway this is something that has at least a certain logic. But what if I do:

```
String[] right = { "nonA", "b", "c" };
// or Collections.singletonList("a");
// or a plain List or Set; does not matter
String[] rightNew = Collections.singleton("a").toArray(right);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rightNew));
```

Taking the previous example as a reference, I would expect this one to show:

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

But, a bit un-expected for me, it prints:

```
[a, null, c]
```

And, of course, I go to the documentation that explicitly says this is expected:

> If this set fits in the specified array with room to spare (i.e., the array has more elements than this set), the element in the array immediately following the end of the set is set to null.

OK, good, this is at least documented. But it later says:

> This is useful in determining the length of this set only if the caller  knows that this set does not contain any null elements.

This is the part in the documentation that confuses me the most :|

And an even funner example that makes little sense to me:

```
String[] middle = { "nonZ", "y", "u", "m" };
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("z");
list.add(null);
list.add("z1");
System.out.println(list.size()); // 3

String[] middleNew = list.toArray(middle);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(middleNew));
```

This will print:

```
[z, null, z1, null]
```

So it clears the last element from the array, but why it would not do that in the first example?

Can someone shed some light here?

Comment: I don't understand the question. They all set the following element to null. Where's the inconsistency?

Comment: @shmosel no inconsistency, the real question is *why* does it happen like this, and is there (and may be will be) code that actually leverages this?

Comment: I guess the assumption is that you may be overwriting data in the destination array, in which case the null value can tell you the upper bound. Doesn't seem terribly useful, tbh.

Comment: @shmosel how about this answer and the comments? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51902457/1059372 does this make more sense? I think it answers my question...

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what your question is. If you're asking how it's useful to set the next element to null if there are preceding nulls, well, it's not. That's exactly what the documentation is saying in your second quote.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)` method on Collection is weird, because it's trying to fulfill two purposes at once.

First, let's look at `toArray()`. This takes the elements from the collection and returns them in an `Object[]`. That is, the component type of the returned array is always `Object`. That's useful, but it doesn't satisfy a couple other use cases:

1) The caller wants to *re-use* an existing array, if possible; and

2) The caller wants to specify the component type of the returned array.

Handling case (1) turns out to be a fairly subtle API problem. The caller wants to re-use an array, so it clearly needs to be passed in. Unlike the no-arg `toArray()` method, which returns an array of the right size, if the caller's array is re-used, we need to a way to return the number of elements copied. OK, let's have an API that looks like this:

```
int toArray(T[] a)
```

The caller passes in an array, which is reused, and the return value is the number of elements copied into it. The array doesn't need to be returned, because the caller already has a reference to it. But what if the array is too small? Well, maybe throw an exception. In fact, that's what [Vector.copyInto](http://file:///Users/src/jdk-doc/jdk10-docs/docs-online/api/java/util/Vector.html#copyInto(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) does.

```
void copyInto​(Object[] anArray)
```

This is a terrible API. Not only does it not return the number of elements copied, it throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the destination array is too short. Since Vector is a concurrent collection, the size might change at any time before the call, so the caller *cannot* guarantee that the destination array is of sufficient size, nor can it know the number of elements copied. The only thing the caller can do is to lock the Vector around the entire sequence:

```
synchronized (vec) {
    Object[] a = new Object[vec.size()];
    vec.copyInto(a);
}
```

Ugh!

The `Collections.toArray(T[])` API avoids this problem by having different behavior if the destination array is too small. Instead of throwing an exception like Vector.copyInto(), it allocates a *new* array of the right size. This trades away the array-reuse case for more reliable operation. The problem is now that caller can't tell whether its array was reused or a new one was allocated. Thus, the return value of `toArray(T[])` needs to return an array: the argument array, if it was large enough, or the newly allocated array.

But now we have another problem. We no longer have a way to tell the caller the number of elements that were copied from the collection into the array. If the destination array was newly allocated, or the array happens to be exactly the right size, then the length of the array is the number of elements copied. If the destination array is larger than the number of elements copied, the method attempts to communicate to the caller the number of elements copied, by writing a `null` to the array location *one beyond* the last element copied from the collection. If it's known that the source collection has no null values, this enables the caller to determine the number of elements copied. After the call, the caller can search for the first null value in the array. If there is one, its position determines the number of elements copied. If there is no null in the array, it knows that the number of elements copied equals the length of the array.

Quite frankly, this is pretty lame. However, given the constraints on the language at the time, I admit I don't have a better alternative.

I don't think I've ever seen any code that reuses arrays or that checks for nulls this way. This is probably a holdover from the early days when memory allocation and garbage collection were expensive, so people wanted to reuse memory as much as possible. More recently, the accepted idiom for using this method has been the second use case described above, that is, to establish the desired component type of the array as follows:

```
MyType[] a = coll.toArray(new MyType[0]);
```

(It seems wasteful to allocate a zero-length array for this purpose, but it turns out that this allocation can be optimized away by the JIT compiler, and the obvious alternative `toArray(new MyType[coll.size()])` is actually slower. This is because of the need to initialize the array to nulls, and then to fill it in with the collection's contents. See Alexey Shipilev's article on this topic, [*Arrays of Wisdom of the Ancients*](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/).)

However, many people find the zero-length array counterintuitive. In JDK 11, there is a new API that allows one to use an array constructor reference instead:

```
MyType[] a = coll.toArray(MyType[]::new);
```

This lets the caller specify the component type of the array, but it lets the collection provide the size information.

Comment: *We no longer have a way to tell the caller the number of elements that were copied from the collection into the array.* Why not check the size of the source collection?

Comment: *In JDK 11, there is a new API that allows one to use an array constructor reference instead.* Sweet. Wasn't that rejected in Java 8 for compatibility reasons?

Comment: @shmosel *Why not check the size of the source collection?* The caller could call size() before or after the call to toArray(). However, the size value might not equal the actual number of elements copied by toArray() if another thread has modified the source collection. Only toArray() knows the exact number of elements copied. Of course this isn’t an issue if you’re single threaded, but the general case is that the source is a concurrent collection.

Comment: @shmosel *Wasn't that rejected in Java 8 for compatibility reasons?* I don’t think so. It fell out of 8 because we ran out of time. There was discussion in the 9 or 10 dev periods about whether this is the most natural API and about performance — the obvious override actually turned out to be slower! We got past those issues during 11 development.

Comment: Found it: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-libs-spec-experts/2013-June/001915.html

Comment: @shmosel Ah yes. There is a source incompatibility, but not one that's so fundamental that by itself it would prevent the API from being added. The feature got dropped from 8 because updating tests in response to the incompatibility would have caused additional work across different teams, and there just wasn't time to coordinate it. When we added the feature for 11 we did run across an app that was impacted by the incompatibility. It's just something that needs to be dealt with during migration.

Answer (score 3):

It will only clear the element in the index *right after* the last element in the original list, so in the first example the list is empty, hence it nullifies the element at index zero (the first element which is `"1"`).

In your last example, it just happens that the last element is the one right after the last element in the original list. Knowing that the last scenario wouldn't really help in determining the size of the list because it *did* allowed null values.

But if the list did not allow null (e.g. [immutable lists introduced in Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#immutable)), then this is useful because in case you're looping over the returned array, **you would not want to process the extra elements**, in which case you can stop the iterator at the first null element.

Comment: you make sense, so you're saying that if that particular `List/Set` would not allow `null`s and you would call `toArray` with an `array` bigger in size than the `List`, while looping over the `array` as soon as you encounter the first null - you would be sure that you are done. This is exactly what is the case for immutable collections in java-9, that prohibit nulls. If you would add this part, I would accept it

Comment: but this is extremely confusing for `ArrayList` (that does accepts nulls) and when you encounter the first null, well, you have no idea if you are done. Well, at least, it is very clear in the documentation.

Comment: @Eugene Yeah you're right, hence it says "_only_ if the caller knows that this set does not contain any null elements."

Comment: @Eugene No big deal, Stuart's answer indeed covers it better and comes from the original developers.

Answer (score 2):

From the JDK 9 source code for `ArrayList`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
    if (a.length < size)
        // Make a new array of a's runtime type, but my contents:
        return (T[]) Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, a.getClass());
    System.arraycopy(elementData, 0, a, 0, size);
    if (a.length > size)
        a[size] = null;
    return a;
}
```

and in `Arrays.ArrayList`, the `List` implementation returned by `Arrays.asList`:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
    int size = size();
    if (a.length < size)
        return Arrays.copyOf(this.a, size,
                             (Class<? extends T[]>) a.getClass());
    System.arraycopy(this.a, 0, a, 0, size);
    if (a.length > size)
        a[size] = null;
    return a;
}
```

If the size of the list to be converted to an array is `size`, then they both set `a[size]` to `null`.

With an empty list, `size` is `0` so `a[0]` is set to `null`, and the other elements are not touched.

With a singleton list, `size` is `1` so `a[1]` is set to `null`, and the other elements are not touched.

If the size of the list is one less than the length of the array, `a[size]` refers to the last element of the array, so it is set to `null`.  In your example, you have a `null` in the second position (index 1), so that is set to `null` as an element.  If someone were looking for `null` to count elements, they would stop here instead of the other `null`, which is the `null` resulting from setting the next element beyond the list's contents to `null`.  These `null`s can't be told apart.

Comment: you are correct, it's jus that the other answer (verbiage wise) is closer to my understanding. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Code of toArray(T[] a) of (for instance) ArrayList is quite clear:

```
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
    if (a.length < size)
        // Make a new array of a's runtime type, but my contents:
        return (T[]) Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, a.getClass());
    System.arraycopy(elementData, 0, a, 0, size);
    if (a.length > size)
        a[size] = null;
    return a;
}
```

If input array's size is bigger than this list's (which means that we can copy all the list's content into this array because it's length is big enough), then the next element reference in the array after all lists content copied (actually the index equal to the size of the list) will be set to point to null.