# Convert a list of functions to can passed to a varargs method arguments

Tags: java, java-8

```
  public Email myMethod(Function<MyObject, String>... functions) { ...  }
```

I created a list of functions and I want to passed to myMethod:

```
     List<Function<MyObject, String>>  functions= new ArrayList<>();
        if (condition1) {
            functions.add(myObject->myObject.getStringX());
        } else {
            functions.add(myObject->myObject.getStringY());
        }
        myMethod(functions);//Does not compile, I must find a solution here 
        to convert my list of functions to an array that can be accepted as 
        myMethod argument
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an `array` of functions, so create an array of such functions and pass it.

Or you can call it with:

```
Function<MyObject, String>[] array = new Function[functions.size()];
functions.toArray(array);
myMethod(array);
```

Just notice that you can not create a generic array, but you can declare one as such.

Comment: I tried this solution but I have a compilation error: T[ ] is not a functional interface.
I tried also this code: 
  `myMethod(new Function<Translator, String>[functions.size()]); `
But still not work

Comment: @Imar no idea where you got that from. did you try this with `javac`?

Comment: You need the stream: `...locations.stream().toArray(...`

Comment: @MaanooAk oh shoot, I have java-11 as the compiler, and it resolves to `Collection::toArray` that was added in 11. My bad

Comment: `functions.toArray(array);` return type not accounted?

Comment: @nullpointer *If the list fits in the specified array, it is returned therein* `List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4);
        Integer[] arr = new Integer[list.size()];

        Integer[] newArr = list.toArray(arr);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        System.out.println(arr == newArr);`

Comment: @nullpointer [see this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902362/collections-emptylist-singleton-singletonlist-list-set-toarray)

Comment: @Eugene yup, I've gone through that thread and Stuart's explanation via another linked question I guess. Thanks for sharing though.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner code I believe could've been

```
Function [] functionsArray = new Function[functions.size()];
for (int i=0;i< functions.size();i++) {
    functionsArray[i] = functions.get(i);
}
myMethod(functionsArray); // unchecked assignment here ofcourse
```

which then my IDE suggests me to write as

```
myMethod(functions.toArray(new Function[0]));
```

Comment: “cleaner” in which regard? A clean solution would be to implement the target method to accept a `List<Function<MyObject, String>>` as you can convert an array to a `List` easily and efficient via `Arrays.asList`, while the opposite direction incorporates copying overhead and unchecked operations…

Comment: @HolgerI meant simplicity of the code, but I do borrow the point that the argument type change in the target method contract is a better way to deal with.

Comment: Can be improved by using: `Arrays.setAll(functionsArray, functions::get);`